# Configuration issue with apache over ftp

Tags: php, linux, apache, ftp

I have two folders where I can store my website (CentOS VPS):

1. `/var/www/html/index.html`
2. `/home/admin/public_html/index.html`

I can either store my web application in the first path, but I don't have FTP access to this folder. I can't see it at all when accessing my FTP with the `admin` account that I received from my service provider.

Or I can use the `/home/admin/public_html`. For this, I tried to:

- change the Root directory in the `httpd.conf` file;
- `restart apache`;

But this totally does not work!!

It continues to redirect me to the `Apache is functioning normally` message (from the `/var/www/html/` path. why is this happening ?

Even if there is no direct solution, please help me into a direction to get this issue solved so I can continue with my actual work.

At work, I'm using `Putty` to connect through `SSH`, at home I use the Mac OSX terminal to access the `VPS`.

**EDIT**:

I called my service provider and he mentioned that it's better to leave the default folder (which is `var/www/html`).

In order to access the file from the client :

1. I created a link to `/var/www` from the `public_html` folder;
2. Gave permission rights to the `www` folder recursively;
3. Connected through SFTP instead of FTP to get access to the folder (normal FTP won't display the folder).

This appears to work rather well.

Comment: what apache version are you running?

Comment: httpd -v returns Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) Thanks

Comment: Sometimes depending on setup root dir is change through the configfile in /etc/apache/sites-avalible/your.site. have yu checked that?

Comment: It could also be a problem with your permissions. run "ls -lia" from /home/admin/public_html/ What does that return?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49770/discussion-between-philip-g-and-kim-gysen)

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote? Please also explain.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Apache doesn't have permission to access /home/admin/public_html.  You would need at a minimum to give group read access to /home/admin and /home/admin/public_html to whatever group apache processes run as.  Usually it's apache, httpd, or www group--check your /etc/passwd file).

If it's say, the 'apache' group:

```
chown :apache /home/admin/admin;
chmod g-w   /home/admin/admin;
chown -R :apache  /home/admin/public_html
```

If apache must write this directory

```
chown -R g+w  /home/admin/public_html
```

Then set the group sticky bit (SGID bit) so on any directory from  /home/admin/public_html on down (only directories).  This will ensure any file created in them will have the same group ownership as the directory.  Here's how you do that

```
find /home/admin/public_html -type d -print | while read i; do SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");chmod g+s $i; IFS=$SAVEIFS; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am going to try to analyze that this evening! Still kinda weird, why it then still takes the file from "/var/www/html/index.html" instead of an error msg, because the httpd.conf file has been adapted already (root directory).

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Even though I have access now, Apache keeps on showing the index.html from the wrong path. I have no idea why, it's driving me insane!

Answer (score 0):

could be selinux related?  Look for `permission denied` in your apache log and have a look in the selinux logs -- `/var/log/secure` on `centos` by my memory

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has this issue, have a look at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
This is where Apache keeps all  virtual hosts (This is used to host more than one website on a single ip address.)  If you see a 000-default file here, this is usually mapped as the default entry or the site you get when you type in the servers ip address and usually points to /var/www.

PS
Have a look at http://www.virtualmin.com/ It's a opensource cpanel alternative that will provide you with a easy to use web based GUI for common web server related tasks including security, mail, databases and antivirus.

Comment: That's the thing I didn't get. How can you change it to another path? I really expected that adapting the httpd.config file and restarting Apache would do the job.

Comment: @KimGysen Do you have a file called /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf ? You can change the path there.

Comment: I don't have this folder, and I also can't locate this file. I find it bizarre. However, my issue was solved by just using the default folder and connecting through SFTP. I'm also not sure why I get a downvote on this question.